# How helpful is SQL Server 2012 new feature column store architecture is if nearly all columns are in use while data retrieval?

Tags: sql-server-2012, query-optimization, database-performance, columnstore

I have huge database of large tables, while data retrieval from multiple tables (query consists of 10 inner joins approx.) it takes too long (10-20 secs or minutes in some case) to fetch data from database. The query requires nearly all columns from most tables and nearly half columns from the rest.

My questions is how helpful is using SQL Server 2012 column store architecture in my case. Currently I am using SQL Server 2008. Any other suggestion for time optimization is welcome as I am great need to optimize this types of queries

```
SELECT Seq.SeqId,Seq.ThreadId, Seq.Subject,LastAccessed, Seq.State, Seq.AlarmSent,Prop.RegionCode ,Seq.Rating , Seq.ClassId, Seq.SeqMedium, 
Seq.SeqPriority, Seq.StatusDate , Seq.SeqCreateDt, Seq.StartDate, Seq.LastModified, Seq.Resolved, Seq.SeqSrcId, Seq.StatusReason , SeqDocument.DocId, 
SeqDocument.IsCheckedOut, SeqDocument.CheckedOutById , SeqDocument.Remarks, Prop.PahLName ,OC.ClassID,OC.ClassName,OC.ClassShortName,OC.Description ,
OC.ParentID,OC2.ClassName AS ParentClassName,OC.OrgID ,CM.DeptID,CM.Severity,CM.Nature ,ST.TargetClsId,ST.TargetSubClsId,ST.TargetId, ST.ResponderActive, 
ST.TargetType, ST.SentDate ,SF.FlowId, SF.InwardNo, SF.OutwardNo,SF.InwardDate,SF.OutwardDate ,SF.FlowOrder,SF.OriginatorState,SF.ResponderState,SF.PrevFlowId ,
SF.SeqFlowSrcClsId,SF.SeqFlowSrcId, OrgP.Name, SF.FlowStatus  , 
CASE Prop.BCPNO  WHEN '' THEN Prop.TempNo  ELSE Prop.BCPNO END  AS FileNo, Prop.DeveloperName ,PROP.BCPNO,PROP.CaseType, Prop.OwnerFName,
PROP.InwardDate as ProposalInwardDate, PROP.CaseTrack ,PROP.TempNo, PROP.FastTrackNo ,Prop.RevNo ,PROP.CTSNo as CTSNo, PROP.FinalPlotNo as FinalPlotNo, 
SeqDocument.CurrentSequence,IsNull(PROP.ProposalID,0) as ProposalID,IsNull(PROP.PlotRegion,0) as PlotRegion,
IsNull(Prop.ReservationID,0) as ReservationID, Prop.ADRunKey,IsNull(Prop.ApplicantName, '') as ApplicantName, Prop.CaseSubType,
IsNull(Prop.OwnerPeth,'') as OwnerPeth,   Prop.ProposedProject, P.Name as ConsultantName, Prop.CURRENTSTAGEID, Seq.SequenceMode, Seq.Sequencebody, 
Seq.Phaseid, PROP.RegionCode, Seq.SequenceNo, Seq.Validity, Seq.BillDate, Seq.BillNo, Seq.TransactionRegion 

FROM Sequence Seq 
INNER JOIN Sequence$Document SeqDocument ON Seq.SeqId = SeqDocument.DocId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassMapping CM ON Seq.ClassId = CM.ClassID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ObjectClass OC ON CM.ClassID = OC.ClassID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ObjectClass  OC2 ON OC.ParentID = OC2.ClassID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sequence_Flow SF ON Seq.SeqID = SF.SeqID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrgPeople OrgP ON Seq.SeqSrcId = OrgP.Id And Seq.SeqSrcClsId = OrgP.ClsId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN TemplateProposals PROP ON Seq.SeqID = PROP.DocId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sequence_Flow_Target ST ON SF.FlowId = ST.FlowId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN People P ON P.PeopleId = PROP.ArchitectId 

WHERE SeqClsId = 6 AND SeqSubClsId = 1  AND Seq.SeqTypId = 3 
AND Seq.SeqSubTypId = 0 AND Seq.State IN (1,2,3,5)  AND ST.ResponderActive IN ('1', '2') 
AND ST.TARGETPOSTID IN (132,1333,135,136 )  
Order By  ProposalInwardDate  DESC
```

This query is taking 50 secs (approx.) on Intel (i5 3.00GHz) 8GB RAM and results in 5676 rows.

Sequence 176232 rows 38 columns,
Sequence$Document 132776 rows 8 columns,
ClassMapping 6 rows 10 columns,
ObjectClass 6 rows 11 columns,
Sequence_Flow 4847730 rows 22 columns,
OrgPeople 4656 rows 11 columns,
TemplateProposals 90889 rows 64 columns,
Sequence_Flow_Target 521621 rows 9 columns,
People 4655 rows 67 columns.

All attributes datatypes are in (numeric, string, Date)

Comment: Join query, Indexes, etc without these information we cannot help you.

Comment: @kai All attributes included in joins are indexed and all 'WHERE' clause attributes are also indexed.

Comment: But are your queries just returning `SELECT *`?

Comment: The datatype and width of these indexed fields?

Comment: @ Aaron Bertrand ::query requires nearly all columns from most tables and nearly half columns from the rest of the tables

Comment: @Kai  :: index fields are numeric

Comment: to get a useful answer you must provide technical details about your environment. so far you said the db is huge (10gb? 100gb? 100tb?), the queries takes too long (how much is 'too long'? how can you say that is 'too long' and is not the best possible performance?) and you require 'all the columns' (how many columns are 'all the columns'? 10? 100? 100000?). with such vague information only wild guesses and generic answers are possible. also you end with a question mark: you are in great need to optimize this type of queries?

Answer (score 1):

The Columnstore Indexes in your case will be less useful - you are using LEFT JOINs which do not support Batch Execution Mode in SQL Server 2012.
You will get improvements on the compression (its quality will depend on how similar & how big your strings columns are), but over all there will be no significant improvement unfortunately.

Migrating to SQL Server 2014 and Clustered Columnstore might help you a lot. :)